# Show different forms within a modal on click of different buttons

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-modal

I'm definitely going about this all wrong but there must be a way to simplify this process.  I have a modal that contains 4 forms all hidden except one that has a class "active". I need to trigger each individual form based on click events from different buttons ie. sign-up / forgot-password / sign-in etc. so when i click the sign-up button the modal appears with the signup form active, clicking the forgot password just switches the form to show the forgot password. and so on.

my thinking was to create:

```
  function modalSwitch() {

  var btnModal   = [$('btn-one'),$('btn-two'),$('btn-three'), $('btn-four')];
  var formModal   = [$('form-one'),$('form-two'),$('form-three'), $('btn-four')];

  btnModal.click(function(){
    if ( btnModal[].attr('class') === formModal[].attr('data-id')) {
      formModal.addClass('active');
    }  
  });
}

modalSwitch();
```

instead of the on click event for :

```
  function modalSwitch() {

  var btnOne   = $('.btn-one'); 
  var btnTwo   = $('.btn-two'); 
  var btnThree = $('.btn-three'); 
  var btnFour  = $('.btn-four'); 
  var btnFive  = $('.btn-five'); 
  var btnSix   = $('.btn-six'); 

  var modalOne   = $('.modal-one'); 
  var modalTwo   = $('.modal-two'); 
  var modalThree = $('.modal-three'); 
  var modalFour  = $('.modal-four'); 
  var modalFive  = $('.modal-five'); 
  var modalSix   = $('.modal-six');

  btnOne.click(function(){
    modalOne.addClass('show');
    modalTwo.removeClass('show');
    modalThree.removeClass('show');
    modalFour.removeClass('show');
    modalFive.removeClass('show');
    modalSix.removeClass('show');
    ....
  });

  }

  modalSwitch();
```

but i'm so lost right now, any help will be appreciated

Comment: `btnModal` and `formModal` should be jQuery variables; they are currently plain arrays. You can select multiple buttons using `$('.btn-one, .btn-two, .btn-three, .btn-four')` for example.

Comment: No idea what you're trying to say here, this is no solution...

Answer (score 0):

You can use data-src attribute to achieve this, for example:

```
<a href="#" class="btn btn-normal open-logs" data-src="my_details" data-heading="My Heading">
                        Demo
                    </a>

<div id="my_details" class="hide">
your form here
</div>
```

Create a css class to hide the div by default.

Something like this to open modal box:

```
$(document).ready(function() {     
    $(".open-logs").click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
       var logId = $(this).data('src');
       var html = $("#"+logId).html();
       $("#myModalLabel").html($(this).data('heading'));
       $("#modalBody").html(html);
       $("#logModal").modal('show');
    });    
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Code below will solve all your query. Code in snippet have an extra set of css and js which will generate bootstrap model for you. You don't need to write conventional and same block of code for all your models.

```js
function simpleSHow(title)
   {
    var msg=$('#simple-div');
    
    BootstrapDialog.show({
     title : title,
     message: $('#simple-div'),
     onhide : function(){
      $('#hidden-div').append(msg);
     }
    });
   }
   
   function complexSHow(title)
   {
    var msg=$('#complex-div');
    
    BootstrapDialog.show({
     title : title,
     message: $('#complex-div'),
     onhide : function(){
      $('#hidden-div').append(msg);
     }
    });
   }
   
   function showDiv1(div_id)
   {
    var msg=$('#lavel-2_div-1');
    BootstrapDialog.show({
     title : 'Level 2 Title',
     message: $('#lavel-2_div-1'),
     onhide : function(){
      $('#hidden-div').append(msg);
     }
    });
   }
   
   function showDiv2(div_id)
   {
    var msg=$('#lavel-2_div-2');
    BootstrapDialog.show({
     title : 'Level 2 Title',
     message: $('#lavel-2_div-2'),
     onhide : function(){
      $('#hidden-div').append(msg);
     }
    });
   }
   
   function showDiv3(div_id)
   {
    var msg=$('#lavel-2_div-3');
    BootstrapDialog.show({
     title : 'Level 2 Title',
     message: $('#lavel-2_div-3'),
     onhide : function(){
      $('#hidden-div').append(msg);
     }
    });
   }
   
   function showDiv4(div_id)
   {
    var msg=$('#lavel-2_div-4');
    BootstrapDialog.show({
     title : 'Level 2 Title',
     message: $('#lavel-2_div-4'),
     onhide : function(){
      $('#hidden-div').append(msg);
     }
    });
   }
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap3-dialog/1.35.3/css/bootstrap-dialog.min.css" rel="stylesheet">


<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap3-dialog/1.35.3/js/bootstrap-dialog.min.js"></script>



<!--  This is a container Div which contains all the div to show when bootstrap dialog opens -->
<div style="display : none" id="hidden-div">
  <div id="simple-div">
    <h1>This is H1 Heading</h1>
    This is most simple coding
    <br>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="showDiv1()">Lavel-2 div-1</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="showDiv2()">Lavel-2 div-2</button>
  </div>

  <div id="lavel-2_div-1">
    <h3>This is Level 2 Header</h3>
    <span style="color : blue;">This is Level 2 Message 1</span>
  </div>

  <div id="lavel-2_div-2">
    <h3>This is Level 2 Header</h3>
    <span style="color : greenyellow;">This is Level 2 Message 2</span>
  </div>

  <div id="lavel-2_div-3">
    <h3>This is Level 2 Header</h3>
    <span style="color : pink;">This is Level 2 Message 3</span>
  </div>
  <div id="lavel-2_div-4">
    <h3>This is Level 2 Header</h3>
    <span style="color : green;">This is Level 2 Message 4</span>
  </div>

  <div class="container-fluid" id="complex-div">

    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="showDiv3()">Lavel-2 div-3</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="showDiv4()">Lavel-2 div-4</button>
    <h2>Panels with Contextual Classes</h2>
    <div class="panel-group">
      <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">Panel with panel-default class</div>
        <div class="panel-body">Panel Content</div>
      </div>

      <div class="panel panel-primary">
        <div class="panel-heading">Panel with panel-primary class</div>
        <div class="panel-body">Panel Content</div>
      </div>

      <div class="panel panel-success">
        <div class="panel-heading">Panel with panel-success class</div>
        <div class="panel-body">Panel Content</div>
      </div>

      <div class="panel panel-info">
        <div class="panel-heading">Panel with panel-info class</div>
        <div class="panel-body">Panel Content</div>
      </div>

      <div class="panel panel-warning">
        <div class="panel-heading">Panel with panel-warning class</div>
        <div class="panel-body">Panel Content</div>
      </div>

      <div class="panel panel-danger">
        <div class="panel-heading">Panel with panel-danger class</div>
        <div class="panel-body">Panel Content</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>

&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="simpleSHow('Hello 1234')">Simple Div Show</button>
&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="complexSHow('Complex 1234')">Complex Div Show</button>
```